# error..name :MongoNetworkError...message: 'Failed to connect to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

i m getting this error when i m running my server ...
my  code under passport.js is

```
      const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
      const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
      const mongoose = require('mongoose');
      const User = mongoose.model('users');
      const keys = require('../config/keys');

      const opts = {};
      opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
      opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey;
      module.exports = passport => {
        passport.use(
        new JwtStrategy(opts , (jwt_payload, done) =>{
          User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
          .then(user =>{
            if(user){
              return done(null,user);
            }
            return done(null,false);
          }
        )
        .catch(err =>console.log(err));
      }));
    };
```

and on running it is showing this error

Comment: Where are you connecting to mongo?

Comment: mongoose
.connect(db)
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));which i have written in server.js